# Saving SAP R/3 Report Output in Local Folder

Tags: abap, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-r3

We are accessing some data in a SAP R/3 System using SAP Dot Net Connector 3.0.

We are now asked to do the following, and would require some advise on how this can be achieved from our program (in VB.NET 2008) using SAP Dot Net Connector:

a) Accesss some standard and customized (I believe they are called Z-Reports written in ABAP) which are there in SAP R/3 System

b) Execute such reports with a given set of parameters

c) Save the output in a local folder

d) Email / Modify the output for further processing

We do not have any ABAP programmer and would like to do this with minimal efforts on SAP side. Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks 
Rahul

Comment: I don't know _SAP Dot Net Connector_: Does it use RFC (remote function calls) or another technique? A 2nd question: You want a minimal effort on SAP side. But can you create at least one function module (SE37 and some developper rights). Which SAP version do you use?

Comment: here is the sample processing code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497235/how-to-fetch-data-from-sap-system-using-sap-net-connector

Answer (score 1):

I did this many years ago using the DCOM Connector and before that Connection Server.. lots of dust on those. Basically you need to develop or utilize existing SAP functionality using the RFC Interface. We did this by extending the BOR using our own BAPI's that either wrapped our function modules or SAP function modules.

Your BAPI interfaces will be your API's you will write to in the .Net Connector. You should be getting the resulting output in an array or object that you can write to a file in VB. Anything you want your program to do that is outside SAP you will have to develop that on your own.

I am not sure you can call a zreport or program directly from the .Net connector without using a BAPI via the RFC interface.

There are better ways to do this in this day and age.