# SAP .NET Connector Upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I am working on upgrading SAP .NET Connector 2.0 to 3.0. After some research I found there are big structural chances in 3.0 which may require me to rewrite entire application.

Is there a way I can reuse the code that is written for 2.0?

If you have any tutorial or a step by step guide please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, NCo 2 used generated proxy classes while NCo 3 uses a generic API. They are quite different approaches and you will probably have to rewrite at least all the code that directly interacts with NCo.

Comment: I know this is quite old but I might be faced with a NCo v2 to v3 update. Did you find any example code that ramped you up from working with v2 proxy classes to the NCo v3 style coding? Any insight appreciated.

Comment: I've answered other questions with some basic function call examples, for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497235/how-to-fetch-data-from-sap-system-using-sap-net-connector/22510653#22510653 . It may be very different from NCo 2, but it is quite easy to use.